# Getting near by places

Tags: android, location, google-play-services

As far as I know, I can get the near by places from user's current location i.e. from latitude and longitude by using google play web service. Can I get the following categorized places. Is there any api to get it? please suggest the solution. Thanks in advance

1. Tourist attractions
2. Restaurants Hangouts
3. Events this week
4. Weekend Getaways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My sad without some research posted the question. I found the answer to my question on [this](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types)